# Convert dates to UTC in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I need to **convert dates in a DB2 Database to UTC values**.

Usually the `TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP` function would be the way to do this, but this method seems to only work if the source time-zone is known. The problem I'm facing is that I need an SQL script, that converts the existing dates from the current time-zone of the database to UTC, *without hard-coding the current time-zone*.

---

**What I already tried** is the following SQL:

```
-- assuming there is a table called 'test' with a column 'col1' of the type timestamp
SELECT col1 AS my_time_zone, TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP(col1, CURRENT TIMEZONE) AS utc FROM test;
```

This does not convert the date value, because `CURRENT TIMEZONE` returns an integer value (in my case 10000 for UTC+01:00). This integer value seems to be converted to a VARCHAR, that cannot be interpreted by the `TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP` function.

From the [DB2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-utc-timestamp):

> timezone-expression
> [...] If the expression is not a VARCHAR, it is cast to VARCHAR before the function is evaluated.
> [...] If the timezone-expression returns a value that is not a time zone in the IANA time zone database, then the value of expression is returned without being adjusted.

---

**So my question is**: Is there a way to get the current time-zone from a DB2 database, in a format that the `TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP` function can use? Or is there any other way to convert dates from the current time-zone to UTC?

Answer (score 0):

That would be simply `col1 - current timezone`, given that `col1` has the `timestamp` data type.

Comment: But that would not take daylight saving time into account. So all values that were saved during summer time (when my time-offset from UTC is +02:00) would be updated wrong.

Comment: Well, then you need to store the timezone in effect along with the timestamp value, or implement a function that would calculate that. You can't just pull information out of thin air.

Comment: The `TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP` function already does the conversion correctly. But only if I enter the from-time-zone as a VARCHAR, which I would need to hard-code.

Comment: @Tobias You could create a variable and use it as shown at the end of the doc you linked.

Comment: For example Java has handling for when DST happens given a timestamp and a timezone. You could write a Java function that does the calculation, wrap that inside an sqlfunction and use that for the update. Its probably a good idea to keep track of which rows that have been updated so you dont update a row more than once.

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini If the conversion is not possible directly, that would be a good workaround. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, date handling in java used to treat dates as timestamps with 0 time. That caused severe headache with DST where dates could flip. Watch out so you don't mistakenly convert any dates (unless you are using java.time)